# Is there any way to avoid using require("module").default when importing ES6 modules with default exports in Babel 7

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, commonjs

I have a config file that exports a JSON object as default

```
//module.js

export default {
  "test": "abc"
}
```

I'm using this in another file as `const json = require("./module")`. The object I get in `json` is

```
{
   "default": {
     "test": "abc"
   }
}
```

Earlier I was on Babel 6 and was using `babel-plugin-add-module-exports` to unwrap the `default` property while using require. Now after moving to Babel 7, this is not working. I read in the Babel 7 [migration guide](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration-api#export-changes) that the support for `add-module-exports` plugin has been discontinued.

Then I found `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` for this purpose. But that too yielded no results. This is my `.babelrc` config

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
      {
        "pragma": "h"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Is this not possible anymore in Babel from version 7 onwards? Do I always have to use the `require("module").default`?

Comment: Generally it's best to use one module system or the other and not both. Why is the JSON file using `export default` while the other code uses `require`?

Comment: I generally use `export default` and `import` only. But in nodejs I'm using the `config` library that uses only `require()`... So that is creating problems

Comment: In this case I prefer do not use export default. I use export const .... then babel compile a object with all export without default key.